# I get a Render error when I am trying to render one of the pages of my React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native

Render Error
[6127,"RCTView", 1, {"collapsable":false, "backgroundColor":4278221567," height":6,"transform":
["translateX":-7.105427357601002-15}, {"translateX"."<>"},{"scaleX"."<>"}]M is not usable as a native method argument

I tried to run the app but when I click on one of the pages, "Challenges" page, it gives me a Render error
Render Error
[6127,"RCTView", 1, {"collapsable":false, "backgroundColor":4278221567," height":6,"transform":
["translateX":-7.105427357601002-15}, {"translateX"."<>"},{"scaleX"."<>"}]M is not usable as a native method argument

This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Pressable,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import * as Progress from "react-native-progress";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Pedometer } from "expo-sensors";
import ChallengesItem from "../components/ChallengesItem";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const Challenges = () => {
  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

  const [searchPhrase, setSearchPhrase] = useState("");
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [masterData, setMasterData] = useState([]);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const challengesRef = firebase.firestore().collection("challenges");

  useEffect(() => {
    challengesRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const users = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const { heading, text, points } = doc.data();
        users.push({
          id: doc.id,
          heading,
          text,
          points,
        });
      });
      setUsers(users);
    });
  }, []);
  let [stepCount, updateStepCount] = useState([0]);
  const subscribe = () => {
    const subscription = Pedometer.watchStepCount((result) =>
      updateStepCount(result.steps)
    );
    Pedometer.isAvailableAsync().then(
      (result) => {
        setPedometerAvailability(String(result));
      },
      (error) => {
        setPedometerAvailability(error);
      }
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    subscribe();
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { text: "Walk a minimum of 15,000 steps today", target: 15000 },
    { text: "Walk at least 5km today", target: 10000 },
    { text: "Burn off 150 calories", target: 150000 },
    { text: "Get at least 10,000 steps", target: 10000 },
  ]);
  const [lastRefreshTime, setLastRefreshTime] = useState(null);
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if more than 24 hours have passed since last refresh
    const now = Date.now();
    if (!lastRefreshTime || now - lastRefreshTime > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
      // Set the last refresh time
      setLastRefreshTime(now);

      // Set the current item
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
      setCurrentItem(items[randomIndex]);
    }
  }, [lastRefreshTime]);

// Get the current day of the year (1 to 365)
// const today = new Date();
// const startOfYear = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
// const diff = today - startOfYear;
// const dayOfYear = Math.floor(diff / 86400000); // milliseconds in a day

// // Use the day of the year as the seed for the random number generator
// Math.seedrandom(dayOfYear);

// // Shuffle the array using the Fisher-Yates algorithm
// for (let i = stringsArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
//   const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
//   [stringsArray[i], stringsArray[j]] = [stringsArray[j], stringsArray[i]];
// }

  const [challenge, setChallenge] = useState([]);
  const AddAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(`Are you sure you want to take on this challenge?`, "WOOOOO", [
      {
        text: "YES, BRING IT ON",
        onPress: () => setChallenge(challenge),
        style: "cancel",
      },
      {
        text: "No I want my mommy",
        onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
        style: "cancel",
      },
    ]);
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 5,
            backgroundColor: "white",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 38 }}>Challenges</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: "#C1CAD6" }}>
            Whatever it is don't give up!
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ padding: 10, marginTop: 5 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold" }}>In Progress</Text>
          {/* <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}> */}
              {/* <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  height: 200,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  width: windowWidth - 50,
                  marginRight: 10,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    height: 200,
                    borderRadius: 15,
                    width: windowWidth - 50,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <>
                    {challenge.map((item) => (
                      <View>
                        <Text
                          style={{
                            color: "white",
                            padding: 5,
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            fontSize: 30,
                            marginBottom: -30,
                          }}
                        >
                          {item.heading}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    ))}
                  </>
                  <Progress.Bar
                    progress={0}
                    width={200}
                    style={{ marginTop: 100 }}
                  />
                </View>
              </View> */}
              <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  top: 10,
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  height: 200,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  width: windowWidth - 50,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    padding: 5,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: 30,
                    marginBottom: -10,
                  }}
                >
                  Daily Challenge
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    padding: 5,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: 15,
                    marginBottom: -30,
                    marginTop: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  {currentItem && <Text>{currentItem.text}</Text>}
                  
                </Text>
                <Progress.Bar
                  progress={stepCount/currentItem?.target}
                  width={200}
                  style={{ marginTop: 100 }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          {/* </ScrollView> */}
        </View>
        <View style={{ padding: 10, marginTop: 5 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold" }}>For you</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          {/*
                backgroundColor: "#FFFF82",
                backgroundColor: "#B5D99C",
           */}
          <FlatList
            style={{ height: "100%" }}
            data={users}
            searchPhrase={searchPhrase}
            setClicked={setClicked}
            numColumns={1}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Pressable style={[styles.containers]}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#E9ECF1",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginBottom: 15,
                    borderRadius: 17,
                    marginHorizontal: 20,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => [setChallenge([...challenge, item])]}
                >
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: "#89B3DD",
                      width: 35,
                      height: 35,
                      borderRadius: 10,
                      alignSelf: "center",
                      marginHorizontal: 15,
                    }}
                  ></View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      flex: 1,
                    }}
                  >
                    <View
                      style={[
                        styles.innerContainer,
                        {
                          paddingHorizontal: 10,
                          width: windowWidth - 130,
                          height: 80,
                          borderRadius: 15,
                          marginLeft: 10,
                          justifyContent: "center",
                        },
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Text
                        style={[
                          styles.itemHeading,
                          { padding: 5, color: "#252C45" },
                        ]}
                      >
                        {item.heading}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={[
                          styles.itemText,
                          { paddingHorizontal: 5, color: "#252C45" },
                        ]}
                      >
                        ✨{item.text}✨
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      width: 70,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 28,
                        marginRight: 10,
                        marginLeft: 10,
                        fontWeight: "800",
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.points}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Pressable>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function ChallengesStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Challenges">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Challenges"
        component={Challenges}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SecondPage"
        component={ChallengesItem}
        options={{ headerShown: true }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowColor: "#171717",
    shadowOffset: { width: -2, height: 4 },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    width: windowWidth - 19,
    borderRadius: 14,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 32,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  innerContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  itemHeading: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontWeight: "300",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  bottomSheet: {
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: -4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  progressBar: {
    height: 15,
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "#000",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
```